# Two main clauses?

Tags: word-order

In Slow German episode 177 she says,

> Aber ich hoffe, Ihr habt jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen, wie die Menschen damals lebten.

I don't understand the word order in this sentence. This seems wrong:

> Ihr habt jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen

Shouldn't it be

habt Ihr jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen?

or

dass Ihr jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen habt?

It looks to me as if these are two main clauses. Is that correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Aber ich hoffe, ihr habt jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen, wie die Menschen damals lebten.
>
> Aber ich hoffe, dass ihr jetzt jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen habt, wie die Menschen damals lebten.

Beide Sätze sind korrekt. Es ist im Deutschen erlaubt und üblich, Hauptsätze allein mit einem Komma zu verbinden. Einen Fehler wie »comma splice« im Englischen gibt es im Deutschen nicht.

*Both sentences are correct. In German, connecting main clauses with a comma alone is allowed and common. Unlike English, there is no »comma splice« error in German.*

> Im Deutschen dient der Punkt dazu, einen Gedankengang abzuschließen, das Komma verbindet hingegen zu einem Gedanken gehörende Sätze, zum Beispiel diesen Gedanken hier, in einer bloßen Verkettung von Hauptsätzen.

In deinem Beispiel ist die Verbindung der beiden Hauptsätze besonders stark, denn nach

*In your example the connection between the two main clauses is especially strong because after*

> Aber ich hoffe, …

muss auf jeden Fall noch ein Wunsch folgen, der gehofft wird. Man kann an dieser Stelle also keinen Punkt setzen. Allerdings kann man den Wunsch sowohl als Präpositionalobjekt mit *auf*, als Objektsatz oder auch als Hauptsatz ergänzen.

*there has to be a wish in any case. One cannot put a full stop here. But you are free to use either a prepositional object with the auf preposition, an object clause, or a main clause to add the wish.*

> Wir hoffen auf Regen.
>
> Wir hoffen, dass bald Regen kommt.
>
> Wir hoffen, es kommt bald Regen.

Besonders tückisch ist diese Konstruktion, wenn der Wunsch **vorangeht**:

*The latter construction is particularily malicious if the wish **leads** the sentence:*

> Es kommt bald Regen, hoffen wir.

So reden Deutschsprecher sehr häufig, und damit bewahrheitet sich einmal mehr, dass man im Deutschen immer erst auf den Punkt warten muss, bevor man den Sinn eines Satzes erfassen kann. Und es kann sehr lange dauern, bis der abschließende Punkt kommt.

*German speakers often talk like this, and it proves again you have to wait and wait and wait for the full stop before you could finally make out the meaning of a German sentence. And though this full stop may happen eventually, it may take a long time.*

---

All dies ist auch nicht auf Wünsche beschränkt:

*All this isn't limited to wishes:*

> Du brauchst eine Pause, denke ich.

Der Übergang zu direkter Rede ist fließend:

*There's a fluent transition to direct speech:*

> »Du liebst mich nicht«, hat sie mir an den Kopf geworfen.

The only difference is *who* wishes, thinks, speaks, acts. As soon it's two different persons, it becomes direct speech.

Comment: Es handelt sich nicht um zwei Hauptsätze. In "Ich hoffe, ihr hab jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen" ist "Ihr habt jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen" Objekt von *hoffen*.

Comment: Das ist ein Hauptsatz als Objekt.

Comment: Objektsätze können keine Hauptsätze sein, denn sie sind abhängig von dem Satz, dessen Objekt sie sind.

Comment: *Ihr habt jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen.* ist eindeutig ein Hauptsatz. Er könnte auch alleine stehen. Daher ja die Frage. In meiner Antwort gehe ich auf alle Richtungen ein, aus der man diese Konstruktion betrachten kann.

Comment: -1: Ein Hauptsatz kann nicht Nebensatz sein. Es handelt sich um einen Nebensatz ohne Konjunktion und mit dem Verb an zweiter Stelle – trotzdem immer noch ein Nebensatz.

Comment: Wie erklärst du *Wir hoffen, es kommt bald Regen.* – Das sind zwei verkettete Hauptsätze. Man kann den zweiten auch als Nebensatz ansehen, muss es aber nicht tun. Klar wird das erst bei der Inversion *Es kommt bald Regen, hoffen wir.* → Die Dinge sind nicht so eindeutig, wie es geschrieben steht.

Comment: *Wir hoffen, es kommt bald Regen* kann man als verkettete Hauptsätze lesen, aber dann wäre die Bedeutung die gleiche wie in: *Wir hoffen. Es kommt bald Regen.* So wird ein Leser das aber nicht verstehen.

Answer (score 4):

It's one of the bigger didactic lies that "main clause order" (with the finite verb in fronted position) is limited to main clauses (i.e. independent clauses). A textbook might operate with contrasts like the following.

> *main clauses*
> **Gibt** es noch Tickets?
> Wo **ist** der Bahnhof?
> Wir **sehen** uns bald wieder.
>
> *subordinate clauses*
> Ich würde gern wissen, **ob** es noch Tickets **gibt**.
> Können Sie mir sagen, **wo** der Bahnhof **ist**?
> Ich hoffe, **dass** wir uns bald **wiedersehen**.

But the last example can be rewritten as:

> Ich hoffe, wir **sehen** uns bald wieder.

These are two sentences with "main clause order". However, as Janka has correctly pointed out, the second one functions as an object within the first one, i.e. it is a dependent clause. It follows that "main clause order" is a misnomer: German allows V2 order (with the finite verb in second position) in dependent clauses.

Spoken German also has relative clauses with V2 order.

> Es gibt Leute, die **regen** mich auf.

Conversely, there are also independent clauses with the finite verb in final position (known as *exclamatives*).

> Was der nicht alles **erzählt**!
> Dass er sich das getraut **hat**!

Answer (score 0):

When a subject or object subordinate clause is not introduced by a conjuction, the word order is the same as in main clauses (verb-second).

Hier "Ihr habt jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen" is object of "hoffen", but without a conjunction ("Uneingeleiteter Objektsatz"). Because of this, the verb-second word order applies and the word order is correct.

", dass ihr jetzt einen Eindruck bekommen habt" is also valid. Here, the subordinate clause has a conjunction, and verb-last is the correct order.